# Android: UI not refreshing with data binding on MutableSet MutableLiveData

Tags: android, kotlin

Here's my XML:

```
android:textColor="@{viewModel.daysSet.contains(viewModel.days.mon) ? @color/selectedText : @color/black }"
```

View Model:

```
val daysSet = MutableLiveData<MutableSet<Days.Day>>().apply {
        value = HashSet<Days.Day>()
    }
```

Whenever daysSet gets changed, the UI does not change. I've also done

```
binding.setLifecycleOwner(viewLifecycleOwner)
```

Adding to the set:

```
fun evalDaySet(day: Days.Day):String {
        val daysSet = daysSet.value
        testText.value=true
        if (!daysSet!!.contains(day)) {
            daysSet.add(day)
            return "Add"
        } else {
            daysSet.remove(day)
            return "Remove"
        }
    }
```

It just doesn't refresh. However, the set is definitely adding and it sets the color when the view is recreated. The binding is not being notified of a change. 
It seems to be a problem with MutableSet. Is there another data structure that works for this goal? Do Maps accomplish this goal? 
It says they are "supported" here:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#collections

Comment: Can you post the code of how and where are updating the live data ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability#observable_objects